# How to take words from parentheses in a column to new columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like below:

```
      Player Name       Headline
1     LeBron James      LeBron James suggests 5-10 games before playoff
2     LeBron James      LeBron James (groin) probable for Thursday 
3     LeBron James      LeBron James overcomes Pelicans with 34/13/12
4     LeBron James      LeBron James (groin) plans to play on Tuesday   
5     LeBron James      LeBron James (rest) questionable Tuesday      
6     LeBron James      LeBron James (leg) will start on Saturday   
7     LeBron James      LeBron James (hip) is questionable 
8     Ryan Anderson     Anderson (flu) returns against Cavs on Sunday   
9     Ryan Anderson     Ryan Anderson out with respiratory infection   
10    Ryan Anderson     Anderson (rest) not playing
```

I want to remove any rows that do not have any `(text)` in the Headline column. Also, I want to have two new columns labeled `Injury/Rest` and `Location` like below.

**The new dataframe output I want:**

```
      Player Name       Headline                           Injury/Rest  Location
2     LeBron James      LeBron James (groin) probable...   Injury       groin
4     LeBron James      LeBron James (groin) plans...      Injury       groin
5     LeBron James      LeBron James (rest) questionable.. Rest         rest
6     LeBron James      LeBron James (leg) will...         Injury       leg
7     LeBron James      LeBron James (sore hip) is...      Injury       sore hip
8     Ryan Anderson     Anderson (flu) returns...          Injury       flu
10    Ryan Anderson     Anderson (rest) not...             Rest         rest
```

As you can see, the rows that didn't have any `(text)` in the Headline column were removed. The ones that have `(text)` were then categorized in a new column `Injury/Rest` and `Location` like above.

I have done `df1 = df[df['Headline'].str.contains("(rest)")]` to extract all the `(rest)` rows from the Headline column. There is over 100k rows so I do not know how to do every injury in the `( )` and add data in the two new columns.

How do I get the output I want to clean up the dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do:

```
df['Location'] = df.Headline.str.extract('\((.*)\)')[0]
df = df[df['Location'].notnull()]
df['Injury/Rest'] = np.where(df['Location'].eq('rest'), 'Rest', 'Injury')
```

Output:

```
    Player Name    Headline                                       Location    Injury/Rest
--  -------------  ---------------------------------------------  ----------  -------------
 2  LeBron James   LeBron James (groin) probable for Thursday     groin       Injury
 4  LeBron James   LeBron James (groin) plans to play on Tuesday  groin       Injury
 5  LeBron James   LeBron James (rest) questionable Tuesday       rest        Rest
 6  LeBron James   LeBron James (leg) will start on Saturday      leg         Injury
 7  LeBron James   LeBron James (hip) is questionable             hip         Injury
 8  Ryan Anderson  Anderson (flu) returns against Cavs on Sunday  flu         Injury
10  Ryan Anderson  Anderson (rest) not playing                    rest        Rest
```

Answer (score 1):

```
              #keep only rows that have text bounded within brackets
res = (df.loc[df.Headline.str.contains(r"\(.+\)")]
              #extract text within brackets
       .assign(Location = lambda x: x.Headline.str.extract(r"((?<=[(]).+(?=\)))"),
               Injury_Rest = lambda x: np.where(x.Location.eq("rest"), "Rest","Injury")
              )
      )

res


     Player Name    Headline                                           Location Injury_Rest
2   LeBron James    LeBron James (groin) probable for Thursday          groin   Injury
4   LeBron James    LeBron James (groin) plans to play on Tuesday       groin   Injury
5   LeBron James    LeBron James (rest) questionable Tuesday            rest    Rest
6   LeBron James    LeBron James (leg) will start on Saturday           leg  Injury
7   LeBron James    LeBron James (hip) is questionable                  hip Injury
8   Ryan Anderson   Anderson (flu) returns against Cavs on Sunday       flu Injury
10  Ryan Anderson   Anderson (rest) not playing                         rest    Rest
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this like so:

```
import pandas as pd


def get_injury_rest(value):
    if "(rest)" in value.lower():
        return "Rest"
    elif "(" and ")" in value:
        return "Injury"


df = pd.read_csv("Players.csv")
df.loc[:, "Injury/Rest"] = [get_injury_rest(value) for value in df.loc[:, "Headline"]]
df = df.dropna()
df.loc[:, "Location"] = [value.split("(")[1].split(")")[0] for value in df.loc[:, "Headline"]]
```